# Does the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{2}},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}},\ldots)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{2}},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{2}},\frac{1}{3^\frac{1}{3}}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4^\frac{1}{2}},\frac{1}{4^\frac{1}{3}},\frac{1}{4^\frac{1}{4}},\ldots)$ converge?

The question is just that. This sequence can be seen as $p$-tails of sequences of the form $(\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{p}})$ (where $p \in \mathbb{N}$) pasted together. As each of the sequences $(\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{p}})$ converges to $0$, I'm quite tempted to think that this one does so too. Since $0$ is the only point it can converge to, it will be enough to prove that it's Cauchy. But so far I've been unable to do so. Thanks ahead.

*[**Note:** I posted a similar question a little while ago. That was an unintentional mistake. This is the question I really wanted to ask.]*

Comment: What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\root n\of n}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Got it. Thanks.

Comment: If a sequence is unbounded, then it is divergent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no. You can consider its subsequences such as: $\left\{\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{n}}\right\}$ and $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$, they have different limts! The first one is $1$ and the sceond one is $0$.

Comment: I was writing the same thing, but too late! (+1)

Comment: @Riemann: is this the consequence of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry! It is an easy question! Isn't it?